# Select an Item from a listview and start a new activity

Tags: android, listview

i am trying to get the value from a listview and set it into a shared preference and start a new activity.

```
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView textViewItem = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listItem));
                // get the clicked item name
                String listItemText = textViewItem.getText().toString();
                //set shared preferences to kasnaam
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MijnKassen.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();

                edit.putString("kasnaam", listItemText); 
                edit.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MijnKassen.this, Kas.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

it works until i want to start an activity.
my logcat output is:

```
06-02 20:32:25.028: W/dalvikvm(21683): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41674e18)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683): Process: com.example.testv3, PID: 21683
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testv3/com.example.testv3.Kas}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at com.example.testv3.Kas.onCreate(Kas.java:88)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
06-02 20:32:25.038: E/AndroidRuntime(21683):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: `at com.example.testv3.Kas.onCreate(Kas.java:88)` the problem is at line 88 of `Kas.java`. Something there is `null`.

Comment: Agreed with @codeMagic. Edit your question and post your `onCreate` method from your Kas `Activity` and tell us which line is line 88.

Comment: here is my oncreate  line 88 is empty. 
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.fragment_mijn_kassen);

   
   new Search().execute();
   }
  

  //line 88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed to declare my listview, here is a piece from my working code.

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MijnKassen.this, mKassenList, R.layout.list_layout, new String[] {TAG_KASNAAM}, new int[]{ R.id.listItem });

        // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Optional: when the user clicks a list item we 
        //could do something.  However, we will choose
        //to do nothing...
        //ListView lv = getListView();  
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView textViewItem = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listItem));
                // get the clicked item name
                String listItemText = textViewItem.getText().toString();

                //set shared preferences to kasnaam
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MijnKassen.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();

                edit.putString("kasnaam", listItemText); 
                edit.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MijnKassen.this, Kas.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```